# Hide dropdown options with Javascript based on keyword in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I need to hide certain options for a product based on the URL they came from. However its a bit tricky for me since I cant target the option value in this situation.

Example URL: http://www.website.com/department/alabama/shirt.html

```
<select id="select_135">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="1849" selected="selected">NONE </option>
    <option value="1850">Alabama 1</option>
    <option value="1851">Alabama 2</option>
    <option value="1852">Arizona</option>
    <option value="1853">California</option>
    <option value="1854">Texas</option>
</select>
```

Is this case I want to hide all options that DONT have the word Alabama, without using the value number. The goal is for this to work site wide, so if they are on another category, it will do the same thing but with the new URL.

So for the next state: http://www.website.com/department/texas/shirt3434.html , it will do the same thing but for the word Texas.

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: your url is fixed ? all text come before /shirt.html?

Comment: They wont be 100% fixed but will follow a pattern, the state will change and the product will change. Alabama, Arizona, Texas, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code . check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rd553aog/2/)

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
 var url = " http://www.website.com/department/alabama/shirt.html";

  // to get URL use below code
  // var url = window.location.href;

 url =  url.split('/');
 var word = url[url.length-2];

 $("#select_135 option").each(function(){
   if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) == -1){
     $(this).hide();   
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: This is close but its doing the opposite. Its hiding Alabama instead of everything without the word Alabama. Also, is there a way to do that so it will work sidewide? in this case I would have to copy the code 40+ times for each category.

Comment: @JohnMoore can't understand your question regarding category

Comment: you can create one js file and add above code in that file and include that js fine in all category page

Comment: Yes, but the code will be on product page. This URL is dynamic and changes based on customer path.

Comment: check commented code in my answer  

var url = window.location.href;   this will get window url

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf to check the occurance of a substring.

```
var url = "http://www.website.com/department/alabama/shirt.html";
var s = $('#select_135 option');
var pieces = url.split("/");
var state = pieces[pieces.length-2];
for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
if(s[i].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(state) > -1) $(s[i]).show();
else $(s[i]).hide();
}
```